# Atomic update of multipart s3

Tags: amazon-s3, atomic

I need to update multiple files to s3 from a Java application. But the catch is we need all the files atomically i.e. All or nothing.

I am unable to find any solution for that. 
Any suggestions are welcome.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

S3 is an eventual consistency store so you'll need some mechanism like _commit.  Parquet format and others do this for you.  The format options depend on your readers, for example, no RedShift bulk loader for Parquet, so AVRO is a better format for that use case.

What common formats are supported by all systems that need to work with these files?

Comment: Parquet doesn't necessarily do this for me. Because when Spark is writing there could be multiple Parquets being written and some of them may be done early and other later. I agree with the _commit approach and that's what kind of done.

Answer (score -1):

Till date only elegant solution I could find was reading it in DataFrame (using spark libs) and write it.

I also implemented basically checking of some commit files (let's say _commit) for locking/sync purposes which is basically done by Spark APIs as well.

Hope that helps. If anyone has any other solution - they are most welcome to please share. :)